# Class 'Mage_Testswatchplus_Helper_Data' not found in root../app/Mage.php on line 547

Tags: helper, ce-1.9.2.2

After I removed 1 extension : I encountered this problem . ( I removed the code , database )

Class `Mage_mageswatchplus_Helper_Data` not found in `root../app/Mage.php on line 547`
Line code in 547:  `self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);`
I have tried many ways , `Config .- > tool > Compilation` is disabled
Plseas,tell me, how fix it!

Comment: did you remove module from `app/etc/module` folder too?

Comment: make sure you removed all cache. and look into log files. you will find from where this helper call happens.

Comment: All files of extension code has been removed. folder / var / remove all

Comment: File system.log not have problem of my extension

Comment: May be that extension helper is accessed somewhere

Comment: I think your are using mageswatchplus helper class any where. So please find mageswatchplus in your code.

Comment: When not delete folder code , I set false in app / etc / modules / myextension.xml it has happened problems

Comment: check in system.log in / var /  folder

Answer (score 3):

Find deleted helper name in `.xml` files and in project directory. Maybe the module's helper is call from another file. Maybe the module name is in system.xml, config.xml or any other class files.